# What does `-map data-re` option in FFMPEG do?

Tags: ffmpeg, mapping, metadata

I am trying to extract and parse KLV data from a video stream. I found the following example in a [Github repository](https://github.com/paretech/klvdata). I am wondering what does the mapping option `data-re` do?

```
$ ffmpeg -i Day\ Flight.mpg -map data-re -codec copy -f data -
```

I understand the rest of the command, and know that `-map` is used to choose streams from inputs. But what does `data-re` mean. I couldn't find any explanation for it (or similar mapping option or stream identifier) in the documentation, e.g. [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) and [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a valid value currently. It could possibly have been a value historically, but I doubt it. Most likely, it "worked" because the map arg parser would ignore additional letters if a lazy evaluation matched a stream and the `d` in `data-re` would match data streams. The parser is no longer that clumsy.

Answer (score 6):

It's a typo and incorrect. The only time you use arbitrary label names is when using `-filter_complex`.

Use:

```
$ ffmpeg -i Day\ Flight.mpg -map 0:d -c copy -f data -
```

I could understand a user trying `data`, but `data-re`? Might be a double typo for `-map data -re`, where `-re` is intended to be the "Read input at native frame rate" input option (`-map data` is still invalid in this case).

Comment: It indeed works and separates the KLV stream into the output file. You can try it. My ffmpeg version is 3.4.8 and I can't change it. The question was if there is any documentation about this mapping "specifier" (?) / "identifier" (?).

Comment: @zardosht No documentation for something that doesn't exist. It's just parsing the `d` in `data-re` which would result in`-map d` which is valid. Newer versions of ffmpeg will result in `Invalid stream specifier: data-re.`